# Xamarin UI Test. Take control's background color ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, automated-tests, ui-testing

I am new to xamarin UI tests.
I need to get color of UIView. As i understand i need to use Invoke method, because there no another tests way to do this. I try to take color by something like

```
var color = app.Query(c => c.Marked("someText").Invoke("BackgroundColor"));
```

or

```
var color = app.Query(c => c.Marked("someText").Invoke("BackgroundColor").Invoke("CGColor").Value());
```

but it returns me object with stars-only string `"******"` or crash in case of `"Value"` using. 
Please, tell me what I am doing wrong?

Also I'm getting "*****" for any wrong request, for example

```
var result = app.Query(x => x.Marked("Mark").Invoke("TextColorAAAAAAA"));
result = {object[1]}    [0] "*****"
```

so xamarin don't know command "Background".

**Update**

Looks like all that time xamarin was waiting for command "backgroundColor", from small letter. But that's not resolving problem. Now it returns empty object, no even default values...

```
[0] {
    red => [

    ],
    alpha => [

    ],
    type => [

    ],
    blue => [

    ],
    green => [

    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the private field `styleString` of `UIColor` like this:

```
var color = app.Query(c => c.Marked("someText").Invoke("backgroundColor").Invoke("styleString"))[0];
```

You should get a string rgb value: `rgb(1,2,3)`

With that, you can just parse the string to get R, G and B elements out of it.

Comment: still got string with `"*****"`. Looks like `Invoke("BackgroundColor")` return such strange format and other manipulations gave no result :(

Comment: @JuniorD. That's strange, I'll give it a try later with my Mac.

Comment: I will be grateful

Comment: @JuniorD. Cool, I get my Mac back today or tomorrow and will check it out.

Comment: Everything works with yours `"styleString"` and backgroundColor with downcase. Thank you very much! Please, edit your `BackgroundColor` to `backgroundColor`  for fully right answer :)

Comment: @JuniorD. Good to finally get a closure to this mystery. ;) Post fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but if someone needs the same for Xamarin Android, you can do the following:

```
int colorValue = Convert.ToInt32(App.Query(x => x.Class("LinearLayout").Invoke("getBackground").Invoke("getColor"))[0]);
var color = Color.FromArgb(colorValue);
return color;
```